# Replacing German chars with Umlaute to simple latin chars php

Tags: php, symfony

I am using symfony with simple straight forward code trying to change any special character like ä Ä ö Ö ü Ü to the a A o O u U. I tried everything i could find

## normalizer

```
echo \Normalizer::normalize("ä");
```

## htmlspecialchars

```
echo htmlspecialchars("ä");
```

and some others solutioin alike these found online but none of them works for me all will output

```
ä
```

and not

```
a
```

not only with ä but with all the other chars i mentioned before.

what am I doing wrong ? or is there any other solution to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one worked for me for a further reference

```
$inputString = "Á,Â,Ã,Ä,Å,Æ,Ç,È,É,Ê,Ë,Ì,Í,Î,Ï,Ð,Ñ,Ò,Ó,Ô,Õ,Ö,×,Ù,Ú,Û,Ü,Ý,Þ,ß,à,á,â,ã,ä,å,æ,ç,è,é,ê,ë,ì,í,î,ï,ð,ñ,ò,ó,ô,õ,ö,ù,ú,û,ü,ý,þ,ÿ";
$extraCharsToRemove = array("\"","'","`","^","~");
echo str_replace($extraCharsToRemove,"",iconv("utf-8","ASCII//TRANSLIT",$inputString));
```

the out put will be

```
A,A,A,A,A,AE,C,E,E,E,E,I,I,I,I,D,N,O,O,O,O,O,x,U,U,U,U,Y,Th,ss,a,a,a,a,a,a,ae,c,e,e,e,e,i,i,i,i,d,n,o,o,o,o,o,u,u,u,u,y,th,y
```

check [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) for a further information

Answer (score 4):

I guess what you want is to [transliterate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) a string - no matter which special characters it may contain - to a string which only contains characters of the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding.

Even if you use PHP's [Normalizer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php), [Transliterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php) and [ext-iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) (like the other answers say) this can be complex.

I use [symfony/string](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/string) (first [released](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-0-string-component) in 2019) which does all that for you:

```php
use Symfony\Component\String\UnicodeString;

$myString = new UnicodeString('Ä ö Ö ü Ü');

echo $myString->ascii(); // 'A o O u U'
```

Answer (score 2):

Such replace is erroneous, because it would produce wrong words (quite a number of German words differ only by presence of umlaut.. you can get even some NSFW results..). There is standard, official rule of replacing diacritics:

- ä → ae
- ö → oe
- ü → ue
- Ä → Ae
- Ö → Oe
- Ü → Ue
- ß → ss (or SZ for capital)

Normalizer::normalize (normalizer_normalize) from your example is originally from java and in PHP it supported only from certain version. Do you realize that you enter Unicode character into  your script code? There is example from manual:

```
<?php
$char_A_ring = "\xC3\x85"; // 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE' (U+00C5)
$char_combining_ring_above = "\xCC\x8A";  // 'COMBINING RING ABOVE' (U+030A)

$char_1 = Normalizer::normalize( $char_A_ring, Normalizer::FORM_C );
$char_2 = Normalizer::normalize( 'A' . $char_combining_ring_above, Normalizer::FORM_C );

echo urlencode($char_1);
echo ' ';
echo urlencode($char_2);
?>
```

(from http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php)

Comment: also this one is not working, as i said i already tried it the outcome of this will remain ä it wont even get an a

Comment: and chaning the way you suggested is as you said more "german" translation but for search engines such as Google it will understand it as a typos specially if you added these to the URL

Comment: @Yamen Imad Nassif it won't understand if that's a type if you get different word. E.g. shon (already, yet) - schoen (beautiful). There are at least two pairs when alternative would be a swearword in german. More sheningans in Dutch.