# Is there any built-in PHP-function to replace German "Umlaute"?

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I have to replace Html-represantation of German "Umlaute" in php-code
I do this like this:

```
Private function replaceHTMLEntities(&$str){
$str = str_replace('&Auml;',chr(196),$str); 
    $str = str_replace('&Ouml;',chr(214),$str);
    $str = str_replace('&Uuml;',chr(220),$str); 
    $str = str_replace('&auml;',chr(228),$str);
    $str = str_replace('&ouml;',chr(246),$str);
    $str = str_replace('&uuml;',chr(252),$str);
    $str = str_replace('&szlig;',chr(223),$str);
}
```

Is there any inbuild-function in php to shorten this code?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php ?

Comment: [Replacing German chars with Umlaute to simple latin chars php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41475937/2943403) and [Replacing accented characters php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3371697/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about build-in function for this but at least you can reduce and optimize you code using `str_replace` with parameters as arrays:

```
private function replaceHTMLEntities(&$str){
    $search  = ['&Auml;', '&Ouml;', '&Uuml;']; // and others...
    $replace = [chr(196), chr(214), chr(220)]; // and others...

    $str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
}
```

*Hint: do not use passing by reference if it is possible. It's harder to debug and changes are not obvious.*

Answer (score 0):

Better Late than never. This what worked for me.

```
$inputString2 = "Schöner Graben Straße. Gülpät Älbeg Ürh Örder ";
function replaceHTMLEntities($str)
{
    $str = str_replace('Ä', 'Ae', $str);
    $str = str_replace('ä', 'ae', $str);
    $str = str_replace('Ö', 'Oe', $str);
    $str = str_replace('ö', 'oe', $str);
    $str = str_replace('Ü', 'Ue', $str);
    $str = str_replace('ü', 'ue', $str);
    $str = str_replace('ß', 'ss', $str);

    return $str;
}

echo replaceHTMLEntities($inputString2);
```